# storing android web browser content to external app

Tags: android, browser, browser-cache

Am currently developing an application, in which I want this app to show and store a list of videos, pictures and maybe html webpage from using android web browser.

Is there a way to store all visited videos, pictures and webpages when using android web browser to an external application?

Can using webview on the application allow storing of such content?

Comment: If by "android web browser", you mean a standalone Web browser app (e.g., Chrome, Firefox), then the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about chrome or default 'internet' app. Would it be possible if I would to use WebView on the external app instead?

Comment: I would say that there is a greater chance that this can work. I have not tried doing this personally.